# using gitolite VREFs for update hook

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to migrate from v2 to v3 of gitolite. The old way of doing a server-side commit message check was to put the check in a repo specific hook in myrepo.git/hooks/update.secondary

In v3 of gitolite, they advise the check to be put in a VREF. The documentation is a little confusing and I am hoping for clarification.

I have added the following in /home/git/.gitolite.rc

```
LOCAL_CODE                  => "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/our_hooks",
```

In my our_hooks directory, I created a VREF folder and put my old update.secondary script in there. In my gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf file, I added the following to the repository I want the script to execute on:

```
repo myrepo
  RW = @my_developers
  - VREF/update.secondary = @my_developers
```

When I try to push, I get a notice that the VREF/update.secondary can not be found. If I change to

```
repo myrepo
  RW = @my_developers
  - /home/git/.gitolite/our_hooks/VREF/update.secondary = @my_developers
```

I don't get any complaints but the hook doesn't appear to run at all.

Am I missing the boat on how to get an additional update check to run using gitolite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation around this is a little confusing, so hopefully this will help others trying to get a chained update hook working with gitolite v3.

Everything I've done above is correct, the missing piece was were my update.secondary script needed to reside.

In the gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf, the configuration should look like:

```
repo myrepo
  RW = @my_developers
  - VREF/update.secondary = @my_developers
```

Then there is a VREF directory in the GL_BINDIR directory. Place your executable update.secondary file in that directory.

The GL_BINDIR is the directory that contains the gitolite binary you ran in order to run: `gitolite setup`

Comment: Thanks. I used a symlink in the VREFs dir to a update.secondary in hooks/common that then searches for and runs update.secondary in each repo.  Should be default functionality IMHO.

Comment: but how can I run an individual hook for each project? how can I manage it from gitolite-admin repository? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To add to the (upvoted) [OP nathasm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392862/nathasm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871875/6309), I have no problem using a `LOCAL_CODE` variable in my `.gitolite.rc` file, as mentioned in the section "alternate location" of "[customising gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#ncloc)".

However, I never managed to use an environment variable.

In other words, this won't work:

```
LOCAL_CODE                  => "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/our_hooks",
```

But this will:

```
LOCAL_CODE                  => "/home/git/.gitolite/our_hooks",
```

Using the full path means that any VREF or hooks declared in /home/git/.gitolite/our_hooks/VREF will be recognized

```
repo myrepo
  RW = @my_developers
  - VREF/update.secondary = @my_developers
```