# Preventing user from changing .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitolite

Is there any why to force user not to change .gitignore file. What I mean is let's say that someone will change or delete this file and push this changes.

Comment: If you're talking on local filesystem level, there might be a way to set `chmod` onto the files of the git working directory, but on the git repository level, there might not be any way to do that.

Comment: Well I'm using gitolite to manage access to repos.

Comment: I would not recommend hooks when you manage repos with Gitolite. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

With [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html), pre-receive Hooks are called [**VREFS**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html) ([Virtual Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510046/gitolite-update-hook-exclude-a-repository/11517112#11517112), also [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358)): don't setup a pre-receive hook directly in repos managed by gitolite, do it by adding a VREF in the  `VREF` directory of the `gitolite-admin` repo, and Gitolite will propagate it to the repos.

The section "[restricting pushes by dir/file name](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME)" illustrates how to restrict pushes by the names of dirs and files changed.
That is one VREF you don't need to add to the `VREF` directory, actually (it is part of the update hook managed by Gitolite. For secondary update hook, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871875/6309)).

So modifying the `gitolite.conf` in the `gitolite-admin` repo, and pushing back that admin repo to the gitolite server is enough.

```
repo foo
        RW+                             =   @senior_devs
        RW                              =   @junior_devs

        -   VREF/NAME/Makefile          =   @junior_devs
```

Comment: This is pretty cool and it's working like a charm :P Thx very much. I have also another question a bit off topic can you advise me a good work flow using GIT with QA team and code reviewer in environment with development, testing, staging and production servers?

Comment: @MarceliPo The git-flow is the current standard, and is a good starting point (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12927985/6309)

Comment: @MarceliPo, If this answered your question, can you mark it as the correct answer so that others visiting will know, and VonC will receive proper attribution? :)

Answer (score 3):

Git is decentralised. Once someone has cloned a repo, it is entirely under their control, including the `.gitignore` file.

What you *can* do is prevent users to push certain files to your server by using a [Git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that checks for the specified file types and refuses the user to push.

Read up on [pre-receive hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks). And write a script that searches for the given file types.

Check your repo `.git/hooks` there will be a list of sample files that show you how to handle it. Also read [this article](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1362/example-git-pre-receive-and-post-receive-hooks-to-avoid-a-signal-13-error/) to avoid an easy mistake to make.

**EDIT**

I'm not any good at shell scripting, but here's a small script that disallows .php and .css files and tells the user before aborting. It's located in `.git/hooks/pre-receive`. Remember to make it executable (`chmod +x`) or else it won't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
  if [[ `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $newrev | grep -e 'css\|php'` != "" ]]
  do
    echo "Cannot push this"
    exit 1;
  fi
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a pre-receive hook on the server side, and refuse the push if `.gitignore` is modified.